# What is the command to sign an ios app in flutter?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I am trying to write a script that will create an ipa from a flutter app. Does the command `flutter build ios` have any arguments where I can pass a provisioning profile and a certificate?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's an argument to pass provisioning profile via the flutter build ios, but what I know is that if you've open at least once (which is normal to write programs) the project on xCode and manually selected a profile, when you run the command `flutter build ios --release` it will manage to sign the app with the profile you've choose.